# How to get Android emoji code point

Tags: android, emoji

I want to fill Android emoji code point to [Mozc's emoji_data.tsv](https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/data/emoji/emoji_data.tsv).
While I found [emoji data list](https://unicodey.com/emoji-data/table.htm), this list don't include latest Android emoji code point list.

Is there latest Android emoji code point list? Or how to get Android emoji code point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all emoji has Android (Google) PUA code points.

Emoji made in Japanese carrier has had different code points, using private user area (PUA). They are called "Carrier Emoji".
Each carriers PUA code points are mapped to Android (Google) PUA code points on Android phones.
Thus, in case we show these carrier emoji on Japanese Android phones sold on a carrier's store, we should use Android (Google) PUA code point.
After all, these carrier emoji were exported to Unicode 6.0 emoji.

That is why only Uncode 6.0 emoji have their own Google PUA code points and newer Unicode 6.1 (or later) emoji do not.