# Facebook/messenger archive contains emoji that I am unable to parse

Tags: python, facebook, unicode, character-encoding, emoji

I can' figure out how to decode facebook's way of encoding emoji in the messenger archive.

Hi everyone, 
I'm trying to code a handy utility to explore messenger's archive file with PYTHON.

The message's file is a "badly encoded "JSON and as stated in this other post: [Facebook JSON badly encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008296/facebook-json-badly-encoded)

Using .encode('latin1').decode('utf8) I've been able to deal with most characters such as "é" or "à" and display them correctly. But I'm having a hard time with emojis, as they seem to be encoded in a different way.

Example of a problematic emoji : \u00f3\u00be\u008c\u00ba

The encoding/decoding does not yield any errors, but Tkinter is not willing to display what the function outputs and gives "_tkinter.TclError: character U+fe33a is above the range (U+0000-U+FFFF) allowed by Tcl". Tkinter is not yet this issue thought because trying to display the same emoji in the consol yields "ó¾º" which clearly isn't what's supposed to be displayed ( it's supposed to be a crying face)

I've tried using the emoji library but it doesn't seem to help any

```py
>>> print(emoji.emojize("\u00f3\u00be\u008c\u00ba"))
'ó¾º'
```

How can I retrieve the proper emoji and display it? 
If it's not possible, how can I detect problematic emojis to maybe sanitize and remove them from the JSON in the first place?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228940/how-can-i-enable-support-for-emoji-in-tkinter-applications

Comment: This is indeed related, but that's my next problem in the list, thanks for answering it in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.encode('latin1').decode('utf8)` is correct - it results in the codepoint `U+fe33a`(""). This codepoint is in a Private Use Area (PUA) (specifically [Supplemental Private Use Area-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas#PUA-A)), so everyone can assign his own meaning to that codepoint (Maybe facebook wanted to use a crying face, when there wasn't yet one in Unicode, so they used PUA?).

Googling for that char ([https://www.google.com/search?q=](https://www.google.com/search?q=%F3%BE%8C%BA)) makes google autocorrect it to `U+1f62d` ("") - sadly I have no idea how google maps `U+fe33a` to `U+1f62d`.

Googling for [U+fe33a site:unicode.org](https://www.google.com/search?q=U%2Bfe33a+site%3Aunicode.org) gives https://unicode.org/L2/L2010/10132-emojidata.pdf, which lists `U+1F62D` as proposed official codepoint.

As that document from unicode lists `U+fe33a` as a codepoint used by google, I searched for [android old emoji codepoints pua](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20old%20emoji%20codepoints%20pua). Among other stuff two actually usable results:

1. [How to get Android emoji code point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943093/how-to-get-android-emoji-code-point) - the question links to :

   - https://unicodey.com/emoji-data/table.htm - a html table, that seems to be acceptably parsable
   - and even better: https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/data/emoji/emoji_data.tsv - a tab sepperated list, that maps modern codepoints to legacy PUA codepoints and other information like this:
     `1F62D    FE33A   E72D    E411`[...]
2. https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/issues/115 - this thread links to:

   - https://github.com/Crissov/noto-emoji/blob/legacy-pua/emoji_aliases.txt - a machine readable document, that translates legacy PUA codepoints to modern codepoints like this:
     `FE33A;1F62D # Google`

I included my search queries in the answer, because non of the results I found are in any way authoritative - but it should be enough, to get your tool working :-)